# Using Javascript, can I dynamically create a button and then remove it as needed?

Tags: javascript, button

Using Javascript and HTML, I am trying to have a series of buttons that when clicked on:
1) Dynamically create 3 sub buttons with different options
2) Once an option is selected, I want to remove the 3 new buttons and save their election out to a variable.

Essentially, I am trying to replicate what I am seeing done at http://interactiverenderings.com/.

Comment: yes, it is entirely possible.

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you one thing. This site is not about "Can I do this?" This site is meant to ask questions like "I tried doing it this way, but facing this problem". So show what you have done so far and what problem you are facing. And more over, if you get solution to your problem you should accept an answer here. To accept answer you should click on the Tick sign near the up down arrows on the left side of answer. You can accept one answer per question.

Comment: Thank you GPRathour. I was not exactly familiar with the procedure for this site. I will abide by your suggestions going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/6YWMB/)
to get you started.

```
 <div id="test"></div>

<script>
var dynamicBtn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
var buttonText=document.createTextNode("Hello...");
dynamicBtn.appendChild(buttonText);
document.body.appendChild(dynamicBtn);
dynamicBtn.onclick = function(){alert("Hi")};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("YOUR_DIV");
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button";
myDiv.appendChild(btn);
```